# How to read "well" from a file in python

Tags: python, file

I have to read a file that has always the same format.

As I know it has the same format I can readline() and tokenize. But I guess there is a way to read it more, how to say it, "pretty to the eyes".

The file I have to read has  this format :

```
Nom NMS-01
MAC AAAAAAAAAAA
UDPport 2019
TCPport 9129
```

I just want a different way to read it without having to tokenize, if that is possbile

Comment: It totally depends on what you want to do: do you want to keep the lines intact, do you want interpret each separate word to a string, or number where appropriate?

Comment: I need the second half of the file, what I mean is I need "NMS-01", "AAAAA", and the ports numbers

Comment: The real question is: how do you want to read the information? Do you want to fill in variables like "mom, mac, udpport and tcpport" in python? Then don't use a text file in the first place, but json instead. Do you just want to read the lines one by one? readline() is your friend. Do you want to parse values to integers or into some other datatype? Read them first, then cast them.

Comment: @Blodorn: What do mean by _having to tokenize_? Reading the file line-by-line and parsing each line with an appropriate function is one possible approach. If you have several 'data blocks' in a single file, detect each data block, separate and parse it on its own. If there is just one block per file I would suggest reading line-by-line (since its a rather simple approach), split each line into a list or tuple of elements and generate a dict for each line. In addition, you could think about using the `csv` module. Not mentioning further data handling and export...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to imply that "tokenizing" is some kind of mysterious and complicated process. But in fact, the thing you are trying to do is exactly *tokenizing*.

Here is a perfectly valid way to read the file you show, break it up into tokens, and store it in a data structure:

```
def read_file_data(data_file_path):
    result = {}
    with open(data_file_path) as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            key, value = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

That wasn't complicated, it wasn't a lot of code, it doesn't need a third-party library, and it's easy to work with:

```
data = read_file_data('path/to/file')
print(data['Nom'])  # prints "NMS-01"
```

Now, this implementation makes many *assumptions* about the structure of the file. Among other things, it assumes:

- The entire file is structured as key/value pairs
- Each key/value pair fits on a single line
- Every line in the file is a key/value pair (no comments or blank lines)
- The key cannot contain space characters
- The value cannot contain newline characters
- The same key does not appear multiple times in the file (or, if it does, it is acceptable for the last value given to be the only one returned)

Some of these assumptions may be false, but they are all true for the data sample you provided.

More generally: if you want to parse some kind of structured data, you need to understand the structure of the data and how values are delimited from each other. That's why common structured data formats like XML, JSON, and YAML (among many others!) were invented. Once you know the *language* you are parsing, *tokenization* is simply the code you write to match up the language with the text of your input.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas does many magical things, so maybe that is prettier for you?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('input.txt',sep = ' ',header=None,index_col=0)
```

This gives you a dataframe that you can manipulate further:

```
0       1
Nom     NMS-01
MAC     AAAAAAAAAAA
UDPport 2019
TCPport 9129
```